# Is there a way to create a test adwords client account?

Tags: google-ads-api

I'd like to to create a test adwords client account so I can use it for adwords API calls with a pending developer token.

I have followed the steps in the doc in [this link](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/first-api-call#create_test_accounts) and successfully created a test manager account (with the red label) using the Google Ads UI.

As required, I did that with a different google id than the one I used for the production manager account.
Then it says in the doc "While logged in to Google Ads as your test manager account, any client accounts you create will automatically be test accounts."
But for me those clients accounts were created as production. No red label, and requesting for budget. 
Any idea what am I doing wrong, or an alternative way to create a client test account?

Appreciate your help,
Tal

Comment: I had the exact same problem. Except Google flagged the new production accounts (which according to their documentation should be test accounts since I'm logged into a test manager account) as breaking rules (account duplication or something) and now they've suspended my real google ads account. The world's worst UI and documentation...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After getting some help from Google Ads API team (see [thread here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/adwords-api/9y4uQJUEUqA)) the answer is:

1. Create a google adwords manager test account, [see here how to](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/accounts-overview#test_accounts)
2. Create a google adwords client test account from within that manager account, [see here how to](https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/7456139?hl=en)

And then, even if you get the billing error message, and you don't see any client accounts created, it's actually there, but hidden. To show it, enable the 'Canceled accounts' checkbox, as seen here:
[image]